# Ordering of attributes makes a difference in C#? Behaving differently in different servers

Tags: c#, .net

I have a properties that has the following validation attributes.

```
[NumberOnly]
[Should start with 02]
[Should be of length 10 digits]
public string Number { get; set;}
```

The crazy thing that freaks me out is, it works different in different serves/environments.

I have the same build of code in 2 different servers, which means same code base.

When I type characters (Alphanumeric) in the number textbox that has the property above in the view model, I see that:

1. one server says number should be 10 digits
2. Another server says number should be digits (Which is correct and I would expect in the above server too)

To add, I found that this is intermittent in some other time, i.e I found these kind of weird things happening some other time, do not have a clue why.

Does anyone have an insight? In my research, I found the ordering doesn't matter. But how to ensure same message in server one?

Comment: Assuming, that you're talking about MVC + DataAnnotations, I've marked this question as a duplicate. As a note: DA's `Validator` uses `PropertyDescriptor` API to retrieve attributes, which doesn't guarantee attributes ordering.

Comment: @Dennis: lol that's fine, but what is the solution to see all error messages as expected in the order in all servers? The answer to this question is what I am after, if you can help please?

Comment: There is answer in the linked question.

Comment: @Dennis: Thank you, but I am afraid I couldn't digest that, would you be interpretting for me in C# code of that answer? Cheers